# XElement conversation in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, linq-to-xml

My problem such:

I need bind last property (here, **XElement("permit", "")**) to DataGrid.

```
policy_zone then1 = new policy_zone("TRUST", "UNTRUST", new policy("100", new Match_Policy("any", "any", "any"), new XElement("permit", "")));
```

till it has such  form (this form i need in order to form Xml using XmlSerialization):

```
<permit></permit>

fr-zone |to-zone| Name |Src-addr|dst-addr| Appl |  Action
-------------------------------------------------------------------
TRUST   |UNTRUS | 100  |  any   |  any   |  any | <permit></permit>
DMZ     |Limpopo| 200  |  any   |  any   |  any | <deny></deny>
```

But now I need convert this to such form ( and do this in XAML):

```
permit
```

I understand how it is done separately:

```
        string xmlSTR = "<permit></permit>";
        txt.Text = XElement.Parse(xmlSTR).Name.ToString();
```

**output:**

```
        permit
```

But I do not understand , how can I do this applying to my XAML. Here,

```
 <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="action" Binding="{Binding  policy.new XElement.Parse(then).Name.ToString()}" Header="Action" Width="80"/>
```

This entry is wrong. No desired result. Help please/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a converter

```
    Binding = "{Binding xmlStr, Converter={StaticResource ParseConverter}}"
```

Converter is,

```
    public class ParseConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value))
        {
            return XElement.Parse((string)value).Name.ToString();
        }
        return value;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        return value;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! True! Excellent method.Unfortunately, not enough privileges to answer in more details/